# How can I align the button right next to the input box?

Tags: c#, html, css

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClientVideoFilePath)
    <form>
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClientVideoFilePath, new { @class = "form-control large-textbox" })
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Upload Video</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I don't understand why my code is giving me weird results. It's showing me a button that is shot way to right of my input box. I want the button right next to it! 
[image: Fml]

Also here is the contents of the `large-textbox` class:

```
.large-textbox {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Is that bootstrap I see in there? In which case it would be `<div class="input-group"><input/><div class="input-group-append"><button/></div></div>` --- [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#button-addons)

Comment: Yes. It *is* bootstrap. I will try this!

Comment: Nope. There is no "input-group-append" class in the bootstrap version I have.

Comment: Tried it, still didn't work. :(

Comment: Ah ok, at quick glance then I would guess that bootstrap just wants `class="form-control"` added to your input then so it knows how to handle it.

Comment: Oh I see you have it there.... hmm, would need to see more to know then. Afraid I have no quick answers now.

Comment: I mean what else do you want to see? I'll show you everything lol, this is literally the only code I have

Comment: I mean this is crazy, what is the standard way to just put a button next to a inputbox in Razor HTML using boostrap form-control class? @ChrisW.

Comment: From the little bit I can see, you're doing it correctly for an input group in bootstrap 3.x, if it were me I would inspect that group and see if you don't have some css class overriding the bootstrap defaults or something somewhere.

Comment: Good idea, I'll check.

Comment: I just upgraded to Bootstrap 4. What a headache.

Comment: Jeez, that's a big jump dude. A lot changes between 3 and 4, hope it serves you well!

Comment: Well It's just a little unit test project im working on anyway lol, I figure i'll try and l;earn it

Comment: Sounds good, personally I'm a Zurb Foundation fan so my bootstrap is rusty anyway. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap element which has **row**(it uses negative margin - v.3.3 and flexbox in v.4+) class always must be followed by element with column class e.g.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12"></div>
   ...and/or...
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

You can either remove the **row** class or add **col*** class right after it.
Also you don't need this style

```
.large-textbox {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

**Edit:** Also if you are using bootstrap 4 rename **input-group-btn** to **input-group-append**